# Safari broken with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'" after updating to Angular 15

Tags: angular, safari

After recently upgrading my Angular version, Safari is consistently broken with some weird syntax error that doesn't specify the line number or file.  All other browsers seem fine.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
> promiseReactionJob
```

My `.browserlistrc` file looks like:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
```

Is there any way to narrow down which request or script is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem by re-adding the `target` option to `tsconfig.app.json`.  After looking through the commit diffs, I noticed that it was removed during the upgrade process.

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020" // removing this breaks Safari!!
  },
```